# Collision Term in the Classical Boltzmann Transport Equation

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, kinetic-theory

I cannot get over the feeling that in the classical derivation of the collision term of Boltzmann's transport equation molecules that are already knocked out of a $(\textbf r, \textbf v)$ space volume are double-counted many times. In essence, my question really is: how can one multiply the number of "bullets" (incoming particles) by the number of "targets" (particles within an infinitesimal spatial-velocity element) to get the number of times a bullet hits a target? Isn't it that one "bullet" can only hit one "target"?

Please allow me to elaborate.

In the classical Boltzmann equation with the 2-body collision term for a gas of a single kind of molecule, the collision term is given as the sum of a gain through collision term and a loss through collision term.

Largely following Huang's Statistical Mechanics, the derivation of the loss term (the rate of decrease of particle density $f(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$ owing to collisions) is reproduced as follows:

To a molecule in a given spatial volume $d^3 r$ about $\textbf r$, whose velocity lies in $d^3 v_1$ about $\textbf v_1$, other molecules of any given velocity $\textbf v_2$ in the same spatial volume pose as an incident beam. The flux of this incident beam is
$$I = |\textbf v_1 - \textbf v_2| f(\textbf r, \textbf v_2, t) d^3 v_2$$

So far so good. But the standard derivation goes on to say that the number of collisions happening in this spatial volume $d^3 r$ during $\delta t$ of the type $\{\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2\} \rightarrow \{\textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2\}$ is given by
$$I \sigma(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2 ; \textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2) d^3 v'_1 d^3 v'_2 \delta t = |\textbf v_1 - \textbf v_2| f(\textbf r, \textbf v_2, t) \sigma(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2 ; \textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2) d^3 v_2 d^3 v'_1 d^3 v'_2 \delta t$$
A comment here from me before continuing on with the derviation: a single collision will knock the molecule with velocity $\textbf v_1$ out of the phase-space volume of $d^3 r d^3 v_1$ around $(\textbf r, \textbf v_1)$, how can it still be at the same location $\textbf r$ and velocity $\textbf v_1$ for the other collisions of the same type $\{\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2\} \rightarrow \{\textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2\}$?

To help drive my point home, let's follow through with the standard derivation: The total rate of loss is obtained by integrating over all $\textbf v_2$, $\textbf v'_1$ and $\textbf v'_2$ and then multiplying the result by the number of molecules within the volume of $d^3 r d^3 v_1$ around $(\textbf r, \textbf v_1)$, i.e.,
$$df|_{\text{loss}} \equiv f(\textbf r, \textbf v_1, t+\delta t) d^3 r d^3 v_1 - f(\textbf r, \textbf v_1, t) d^3 r d^3 v_1 \\ = f(\textbf r, \textbf v_1, t) d^3 r d^3 v_1 \iiint |\textbf v_1 - \textbf v_2| f(\textbf r, \textbf v_2, t) \sigma(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2 ; \textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2) d^3 v_2 d^3 v'_1 d^3 v'_2 \delta t$$

To me, this further indicates that each molecule within $d^3 r d^3 v_1$ around $(\textbf r, \textbf v_1)$ undergoes $n$ number of collisions where $n = \iiint |\textbf v_1 - \textbf v_2| f(\textbf r, \textbf v_2, t) \sigma(\textbf v_1, \textbf v_2 ; \textbf v'_1, \textbf v'_2) d^3 v_2 d^3 v'_1 d^3 v'_2 \delta t$.

How are these multiple collisions possible? Isn't this double-counting?

The above is reproduced based on the derivation given in Huang's Statistical Mechanics, essentially same derivations can be found from multiple sources online, e.g., https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/plasma/Plasma/node33.html

Answer (score 2):

The particles are **not counted double**. There are **losses and gains to our phase space due to collisions** which would force us to evaluate separate integrals (primed and non-primed velocity space). For **elastic collisions** the process is **reversible** and we can consider the reverse process.

Maybe it is easier to understand in the following way which can be found in the German-language book about molecular gas dynamics by [Dieter Hänel](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9783540442479). I will choose a nomenclature very similar to his as I try to keep my nomenclature consistent across my answers here on Stack Exchange.

---

**Stoßzahl**

The **Stoßzahl** $Z_s$ is the number of collisions per time and space.

In order to determine it, we could integrate the flux of particles with velocity $\vec \xi_1$ that can be found in an area element perpendicular to the relative velocity

$$ \vec g = \vec \xi_1 - \vec \xi, $$

the so called differential cross-section $A_c$ around the particles with velocity $\vec \xi$. Putting this together we find

$$ d Z_s = | \vec g| f(\vec \xi_1) d \vec \xi_1 d A_c f(\vec \xi) d \vec \xi.$$

Now to determine the total number of collision we will have to integrate over all possible velocity combinations of $\vec \xi_1$ and $\vec \xi$ as well as the cross-section, which for [central collisions of rigid spherical particles of equal size](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/513785/245414) does not depends on $\vec \xi_1$ and $\vec \xi$ and is given by $ A_c = d^2 \pi $.

$$Z_s = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi } \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1 } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g| f( \vec \xi_1 ) f ( \vec \xi) d A_c d \vec \xi_1 d \vec \xi $$

**The collision term in the Boltzmann equation**

For determining the right-hand-side of the Boltzmann equation we look at losses and gains due to collisions in a similar way. Our **phase-space volume** is given by

$$\Delta V \Delta \vec \xi := \Delta x \Delta y \Delta z \Delta \xi_x \Delta \xi_y \Delta \xi_z$$

and correspondingly the number of molecules in this phase volume is

$$ \Delta N(\vec \xi, \vec r, t) = f(\vec \xi, \vec r, t) \Delta V \Delta \vec \xi$$

Obviously after collision the particles likely will leave the space volume of interest with velocities $\vec \xi'$ and $\vec \xi_1'$. We take a similar approach to determining the Stoßzahl but in this case we will not integrate over $\vec \xi$: $d \vec \xi$ will be replaced by $\Delta \vec \xi$. The corresponding specific **loss** flux is then given by

$$\frac{\Delta N_{\text{loss}}}{\Delta V \Delta t} = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1 } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g| f( \vec \xi_1 ) f ( \vec \xi) d A_c d \vec \xi_1 \Delta \vec \xi. $$

Dividing by the velocity element we obtain the change of $f$ caused by collisions

$$df |_{\text{loss}} = \frac{\Delta N_{\text{loss}}}{\Delta V \Delta \vec \xi \Delta t} = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1 } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g| f( \vec \xi_1 ) f ( \vec \xi) d A_c d \vec \xi_1. $$

Similarly our **gains** can be evaluated. As the **elastic collisions are reversible** this can be done by evaluating the inverse collision

$$\frac{\Delta N_{\text{gain}}}{\Delta V \Delta \vec \xi' \Delta t} = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1' } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g'| f( \vec \xi_1' ) f ( \vec \xi') d A_c d \vec \xi_1' = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1' } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g'| f_1' f' d A_c d \vec \xi_1'. $$

The two integrals can be combined with the laws for elastic collisions. As a consequence of the conservation of mass

$$ m_1 + m  = m_1' + m', $$

momentum

$$ m_1 \vec \xi_1 + m \vec \xi = m_1' \vec \xi_1' + m' \vec \xi', $$

and energy

$$ \frac{m_1 \vec \xi_1^2}{2} + \frac{m \vec \xi^2}{2} = \frac{m_1' \vec \xi_1'^2}{2} + \frac{m' \vec \xi'^2}{2}, $$

before and after collisions we can determine the velocity of the common center of gravity as

$$\vec G = \frac{m_1 \vec \xi_1 + m \vec \xi}{m_1 + m} = \frac{m_1 \vec \xi_1' + m \vec \xi'}{m_1 + m} = \vec G'$$

and find that the relative velocity for [elastic collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_collision) behaves like

$$ \vec g = - \vec g' .$$

The transformation for the volume of absolute velocities can be transformed into the system of absolute and relative velocities by

$$d \vec \xi_1 d \vec \xi = \underbrace{det | J |}_1 d \vec g d \vec G$$

with the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) (you would have to rearrange the equation system given by the conservation equations to find the relations and that $det | J | = 1$, basically that the transformation conserves its volume during the transformation)

$$ J = \left( \begin{matrix}
\frac{\partial \vec \xi}{\partial \vec g} & \frac{\partial \vec \xi}{\partial \vec G} \\
\frac{\partial \vec \xi_1}{\partial \vec g} & \frac{\partial \vec \xi_1}{\partial \vec G}
\end{matrix} \right)$$

and therefore the transformation rule

$$ |\vec g'| d \vec \xi_1' \Delta \vec \xi' = |\vec g| d \vec \xi_1 \Delta \vec \xi $$

holds.

This leads to the gain term

$$df |_{\text{gain}} = \frac{\Delta N_{\text{gain}}}{\Delta V \Delta \vec \xi \Delta t} = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1 } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g| f_1' f' d A_c d \vec \xi_1. $$

And as a consequence the **entire collision term** can be written as

$$df |_{\text{collision}} = \frac{\Delta N_{\text{gain}} - N_{\text{loss}}}{\Delta V \Delta \vec \xi \Delta t} = \int\limits_{ \vec \xi_1 } \int\limits_{ A_c } |\vec g| (f_1' f' - f f_1 ) d A_c d \vec \xi_1. $$

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply. I think we agree on the following facts:     

1) The number of particles inside the infinitesimal spatial-velocity element at $$(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi})$ is $f(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi}) d\vec{r} d\vec{\xi}$$

2) The number of particles with velocity $\vec{\xi}_1$ impinging on the spatial-velocity element at $(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi})$ is $$|\vec{g}|f(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi}_1) dA_c d\vec{\xi}_1$$

Comment: You multiplied the two to arrive at the number of collisions $$dZ_s = |\vec{g}|f(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi}_1) d\vec{\xi}_1 dA_c f(\vec{r}, \vec{\xi}) d\vec{r} d\vec{\xi}$$ But my question is precisely this: how can one multiply the number of "targets" by the number of "bullets" to get the number of times a bullet hits a target? Isn't it that one "bullet" can only hit one "target"?

Comment: @JXU I think I understand your question only now. We are not dealing with particles that get knocked out but with **probabilities of particles**. We are looking at the chance that a certain probability of a phase space volume $( \vec r, \vec \xi)$ is changed by collisions with a phase space volume $( \vec r_a, \vec \xi_a)$ or $( \vec r_b, \vec \xi_b)$ with a certain probability $f_a$ or $f_b$ respectively. Thus we have to **consider every single possibility**.

Comment: @JXU If you gamble and there are several prizes to win and you want to determine your chance of winning, then you will consider your chance of wining any of those prices and sum them up. Of course you can only win one of them but in a parallel universe you might win a different one. Similarly with the collisions, of course a single collision will knock out the particle out of phase space element under consideration but you will have to **consider with which probability particles of different phase space volumes will meet in the first place**.

Comment: @2b-tThank you very much for following up and for the considerate reply. I think we are approaching a solution here. I'll reply as soon as I get a little break later today.

Comment: @2b-tHere is where I think the confusion arises and how it can be resolved.

I was not clear on the definition of $f(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$ as it is vaguely defined as the "particle distribution" in many sources. In fact $f(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$ is the **ensemble-averaged** particle density. A more appropriate symbology should be $\langle \varrho(\textbf r, \textbf v, t) \rangle$ where $\varrho(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$ represents the number density of particles for a given **microstate** in the ensemble.

Comment: @2b-tGiven **independence** (Stosszahlansatz), it's easy to show $$\langle \varrho(\textbf r, \textbf v, t) \rangle = Nf_1(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$$ where $f_1(\textbf r, \textbf v, t)$ is the probability density function of any given particle in the gas and $N$ is the total number of particles.

Comment: @2b-tFurther, based on the fact that all particles are distinguishable but identical and their pdf's are independent, one can show in a few steps that the **ensemble-averaged** number of particle pairs with one particle in a phase-space volume element around $(\textbf r, \textbf v)$ and another around $(\textbf r', \textbf v')$ is given by $$\langle \# \text{ of particle pairs}
\rangle = \langle \varrho(\textbf r, \textbf v, t) \rangle d^3 r d^3 v \langle \varrho(\textbf r', \textbf v', t) \rangle d^3 r' d^3 v'$$ This result is not true in general, but only guaranteed by independence.

Comment: Once we have the formula for the **ensemble-averaged** number of particle pairs figured out, the **ensemble-averaged** number of collisions follows trivially.

The validity of the functional form of the collision term relies on the correct definition of the particle density function and the independence among particles.

Comment: @JXU I am not sure if I understand your notation correctly but the idea of $f$ is to generalise the idea of density to a system of particles with a certain microscopic velocity $\vec \xi$. The particle density function is a measure for number of particles in a certain phase volume (space and velocity) and thus implicitely in time $f(\vec x, \vec \xi, t):= \frac{d N}{d \vec x d \vec \xi}$. If you integrate over velocity space you get the number density $n( \vec x, t)=\int f(\vec x, \vec \xi, t) d \vec \xi$ and if you multiply it by the particle mass you get the macroscopic density $\rho=m_P n$.

Comment: @JXU Of course the distribution $f(\vec x, \vec \xi, t)$ is normalised so you could introduce a measure for what fictional fraction of molecules belongs to a certain phase space element but of course this would be zero for any given point for a continuous probability distribution.

Comment: @JXU Correct, the Stoßzahlansatz relies entirely on the assumption that the distributions can be assumed as independent. The reasoning behind this is probably that due to the enormous number of collisions the time frame over which the behaviour of the model gas can be predicted is very limited. So you may assume that there are no obvious correlations between particles anymore, a so called one-sided (before collision) molecular chaos.